# Send #define line with packets from server to client

Tags: packets

I have a game server. He communicates with the client via packet. I want to send line
`#define` From the server to the client with a packet.
In this way not I be forced to recompile the source to the client always.

Basically I can activate functions that are source directly from server to client.

I just need an example about this. :D Please help.

```
typedef struct define_packet_send {
BYTE header;
int define_max_len[20];
long data;
}
```

But how to send the define in a specific file. I hope you guys you understand what i mean.

Comment: You can send it as simple text, or?

Comment: yes, just simple text...  I think.

Comment: Is this about C/C++? Or about packets in general?